# Is orientation="horizontal" in p:tree is available in primefaces-3.3.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to know that orientation ="horizontal" is available in p:tree in primefaces-3.3.1 version and also want to know orientation="vertical also available or not .

Comment: You could easily verify that yourself by reading the documentation

Answer (score 0):

See documentation : http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_3.pdf

Page 420 - 430 for `<p:Tree>` element.